# XSLT: How to select any node inside <xsl:for-each select="1 to n"></xsl:for-each>

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document>
  <planning>
    <meeting day="1" time-period="2" start="8">
      First meeting
    </meeting>
    <meeting day="3" time-period="6" start="9">
      Second meeting
    </meeting>
    <meeting day="4" time-period="1" start="14">
      Third meeting
    </meeting>
  </planning>
</document>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Meeting Schedule</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Monday</th>
            <th>Tuesday</th>
            <th>Wednesday</th>
            <th>Thursday</th>
            <th>Friday</th>
            <th>Saturday</th>
            <th>Sunday</th>
          </tr>
          <!-- Iterate over the time periods from 8-17 -->
          <xsl:for-each select="8 to 17">
            <tr>
              <!-- Display the current time period in the left column -->
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>:00 - <xsl:value-of select=". + 1"/>:00
              </td>
              <!-- Iterate over the days of the week -->
              <xsl:for-each select="1 to 7">
                <td>
                  <!-- Check if the current time period and day match any of the meetings -->
                  <xsl:for-each select="document/planning/meeting[@day = current()]">
                    <!-- Check if the current time period is within the duration of the meeting -->
                    <xsl:if test="@start &lt; current() and current() &lt; @start + @time-period">
                      <input type="checkbox" checked="checked"/>
                    </xsl:if>
                  </xsl:for-each>
                </td>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

At the line

```
              <xsl:for-each select="document/planning/meeting[@day = current()]">
```

I got the error:

> Context item for child axis is not a node - supplied:xs:integer('1')

.

I also tried with this code:

```
          <xsl:for-each select="//meeting[@day = current()]">
```

And then I got this error:

> Context item for '/' must be a node

I always have this trouble when I want to select any node inside `<xsl:for-each "1 to n"></xsl:for-each>`

I am using [XSLT3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xslt3) for the compilation, the command i use is: `xslt3 -xsl:../stylesheets/input.xsl -s:../stylesheets/input.xml -o:../output/output.html -t`

Thank you for help!

Comment: If you're using XSLT 3.0 then why is your question tagged as `xslt-1.0` and why does your stylesheet declare `version=1.0"`? You cannot use `<xsl:for-each select="8 to 17">` in XSLT 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

The instruction:

```
<xsl:for-each select="8 to 17">
```

puts you in the context of the sequence of integers 8 to 17. That means you're no longer in the context of the input XML document and cannot refer to its nodes directly.

Define a variable that binds to the input XML document or part of it and use it to refer to its nodes - for example:

```
<xsl:variable name="xml" select="/" />
...
<xsl:for-each select="1 to 7">
...
<xsl:for-each select="$xml/document/planning/meeting[@day = current()]">
```

---

P.S. Instead of:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$xml/document/planning/meeting[@day = current()]">
```

consider defining a [**key**](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#key) as:

```
<xsl:key name="meeting-by-date" match="meeting" use="@day" />
```

then use it as:

```
<xsl:for-each select="key('meeting-by-date', ., $xml)">
```

Comment: Thanks! It works by defining a variable as the document node. But the suggestion doesn't work, I got this error:   xsl:key cannot be a child of table

Comment: `xsl:key` must be a top-level element - i.e.  a child of `xsl:stylesheet`.